# How would I set up JQuery into an Object Literal module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, object-literal

I'm working on understanding the Object Literal design pattern in JS with JQuery. I have the code separated into different modules to lower the number of time the DOM has to be searched and be extendable. The problem is i don't know how to get the code to actually work. I understand why it's separated such as caching the Dom, binding events, and rendering the action of the slideToggle but the trouble is I don't fully understand how to apply the function to the event correctly.

The code I'm transferring from JQuery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-button').click(
    function(){
        $('#menu').slideToggle(400);
    }
  );
  $('.dropdown').click(
    function(){
        $('.dropdown-content').slideToggle(500);
    }
  );
});
```

The Object Literal Module I'm transferring this to is as follows:

```
(function() {
  var menu = {
    init: function() {
        this.cacheDom();
        this.bindEvents();
        this.action();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
        this.$el = $('nav');
        this.$menu = this.$el.find('#menu');
        this.$menuButton = this.$el.find('#menu-button');
        this.$dropdown = this.$el.find('.dropdown');
        this.$dropdownContent = this.$el.find('.dropdown-content');
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        this.$menuButton.on('click', this.slideToggle.bind(this));
        this.$dropdownContent.on('click', this.slideToggle.bind(this));
    },
    action: function() {
        this.slideToggle();
    },
  }
  menu.init();
})()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: (function($) { /* your code */ })(jQuery); ???

Comment: Is there anything which is failing ?

Comment: @Rayon I get no errors but the action of slideToggle in JQuery isn't functioning

Comment: @Deep I don't understand your comment could you elaborate?

Comment: @ewill, Can you show up an example/fiddle ?

Comment: @Rayon Sure here is a link. https://jsfiddle.net/ewillstudios/y80wabpe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bindEvents` method, `this` refers to `menu` object which does not have `slideToggle` method.

```js
(function() {
  var menu = {
    init: function() {
      this.cacheDom();
      this.bindEvents();
      //this.action();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
      this.$el = $('nav');
      this.$menu = this.$el.find('#menu');
      this.$menuButton = this.$el.find('#menu-button');
      this.$dropdown = this.$el.find('.dropdown');
      this.$dropdownContent = this.$el.find('.dropdown-content');
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      this.$menuButton.on('click', function() {
        this.$menu.slideToggle()
      }.bind(this));
      this.$dropdownContent.on('click', function() {
        this.$dropdownContent.slideToggle()
      }.bind(this));
    },
    action: function() {
      this.slideToggle();
    },
  }
  menu.init();
})()
```

```css
#menu-button {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 644px) {
  #menu {
    display: none;
  }
  nav[role="full-horizontal"] {
    float: none;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav[role="full-horizontal"] ul {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav[role="full-horizontal"] ul > li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: .75rem;
    margin: 0;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
  #menu-button {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav role="full-horizontal">
    <div class="cf">
      <a id="menu-button" href="#">MENU</a>
    </div>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/work">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/blog">Articles</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="">Posts Admin</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Projects Admin</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">Categories Admin</a>
            <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/y80wabpe/1/)

Comment: Thank you, this works, but I was trying to refrain from putting the `slideToggle()` function within the `bindEvents` object. I only wanted `bindEvents` to bind the click event, then have an additional object that it would refer to, to perform the action of `slideToggle()`.

Comment: Then why are you invoking `this.slideToggle`, you should invoke `this.action`

Comment: I realized that I was doing a little much for the desired effect I was trying to get. The main focus was to understand and write code in a more pleasing and readable way. More so to improve in general. Thank you, your answer really helped me out.